# Adding / Subtracting numbers automatically using JQuery cannot subtract properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, numbers

I create a form where numbers have to add/subs automatically based on the input given, all the `adding` part is correct like what I want to achieve, but if I remove number then it leaves `1` in total field whenever data is not there also, and also if I removed all digits at a time but it doesn't subtract.

You can see from below and sorry for my bad English.

Note: 1. Enter a number and delete `1 by 1` then check the total (which is not editable). 2. Enter numbers, select all numbers and remove then check total and you'll understand my problems.

```js
$(document).on('input change blur', '.input_first, .input_second', updateSchedule);

function updateSchedule() {
  var sum = 0, sum1 = 0, total = 0;
  $('.input_first, .input_second').each(function(i) {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('input_first')) {
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        $('#first_total').val(sum.toFixed(2));
        $('#all_total').val(sum.toFixed(2));
      } else if($(this).hasClass('input_second')) {
        sum1 += parseFloat(this.value);
        $('#second_total').val(sum1.toFixed(2));
        total = parseFloat(sum + sum1);
        $('#all_total').val(total.toFixed(2));
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    1st data<br>
    <input type="number" class="input_first" placeholder="enter">
    <input type="number" class="input_first" placeholder="enter">
    <input type="number" readonly id="first_total">
    <hr>

    2nd Data<br>
    <input type="number" class="input_second" placeholder="enter">
    <input type="number" class="input_second" placeholder="enter">
    <input type="number" readonly id="second_total">
    <hr>

    Total all<br>
    <input type="number" readonly id="all_total">
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you were supposed to do the `else statement` to you current function

```
function updateSchedule() {
  var sum = 0, sum1 = 0, total = 0;
  $('.input_first, .input_second').each(function(i) {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      .....
    }else{
       //todo clear the total field
       $('#all_total').val(0.00);
    }
  });
}
```

Clear the total field each time you have `Nan` preferably saving it as `zero 0`

Comment: In another page, i used the same format to add/sub numbers, but only if condition (inside parent if, not elseif) then everything works fine, ill try your suggestions

Comment: it's working, but not like what I expected, It's calculated after all fields data entered only. And that's not what I want to achieve